# How do I filter out only those reviews from excel file that have the specific words I mention in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel file loaded into pandas and want to filter out those movie reviews that have the specific word I mention in the code. Perhaps, I have written certain code but it is not giving the complete and correct output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# reading data file
df = pd.read_excel('./data-for-group-project1(original).xlsx') 
# preparing data
# reading data file  replacing any NaN value in the data
df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
# filtering data
df = df[df['reviewcontent'].str.contains('jamaican')]
# displaying
print(df[['rid', 'user_name', 'rating', 'numberofuseful', 'reviewcontent']])
```

Comment: Code seems good, only `df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)` should be `df = df.fillna('')`, there is some problem?

Comment: Please provide example data.

Comment: [JFYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)